Reference on the Partition Problem's existence of a Solution
I would like to find some references on this problem

Let $I_n$ denote the set of numbers $\{1, \cdots, n\}$. Show that
given any $n$ distinct numbers $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ from the set
$I_{\frac{3n}{2}}$, we can find two disjoint subsets of indexes $I$
and $J$ with $I \cup J = I_n$ such that the difference $\sum_{i \in
> I}a_i$ and $\sum_{j \in J}a_j$ is at most $1$.

Most of what I found on SE was more concerned to the computational aspects of the problem, not so much related to the existence of a solution, in this case in particular I would also be curious on what the best constant is to this problem.
I didn't find much more about this in particular, my progress so far is that I found an algorithmic way to find the best possible partition. By restating the problem as balancing one.
We want to choose $\epsilon_i \in \{-1, 1\}$ such that $|\sum \epsilon_ia_i| \le 1$, we can do this inductively, first notice that this is equivalent to minimzing $\left(\sum \epsilon_ia_i\right)^2$, let $s = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\epsilon_ia_i$, so we choose $\epsilon_{k+1}$ such that it minimizes $(s + \epsilon_{k+1}a_{k+1})^2 = s^2 + 2s\epsilon_{k+1}a_{k+1} + a_{k+1}^2$ by having the opposite sign of $s$.
